# Factory Girl associations with three objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a form object that has form fields (via foreign key form_id)

A form has many form_fields.

There are also form_field_labels associated with form_fields (via foreign key field_id)

A form_field has one form_field_label.

I am trying to connstruct some basic factories so I can test out my forms, methods and validations.

Here is what I have so far:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :default_form , class: Form do
    form_name "Default Form"
    form_url "default"
    enctype "multipart/form-data"
    form_type ""
    form_layout "1_column" 
    group_id 0
    response_fields "photo,first_name,last_name"
    default_form 0 
    language "en"
    submit_button_text "Submit" 
    reset_button_text "Reset" 
    default_dropdown_text "Please Select" 
    sort 0 
    default_status "NEW"
    apply_flag false
    require_advisory false
    add_button_text "Add Another Applicant"
    follows_group_default false

    factory :default_form_with_fields do
      ignore do
                form_fields_count 5
                form_field_labels_count 5
      end

      after(:create) do |form, evaluator|
                FactoryGirl.create_list(:form_field, evaluator.form_fields_count, form: form)
              end
    end
end 
end
```

I copied the create_list function from the FactoryGirl github page, and have no idea if it's necessary for my test case, where I just want to have a factory for that basic Form->form_fields->form_field_label relationship.

The after createblock seems to get my default form fields set up properly. THe problem is that I need for every form_field to have an associated form_field_label.

In our schema, there is no such thing as a form_field without a form_field_label.

I'm new to factory girl, and would like to set up at least these basic associations, so that whenever I have a form, it automatically creates some test form_fields (Through factory girl) and some test form_field_labels.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is for your newly-created form to have a single record in its `form_fields` association with a `field_label`, then you don't really need to use `create_list`. You can just use a normal `FactoryGirl.create` in an `after(:create)` callback.

I'd suggest creating factories for all three objects: form, form fields, and form field labels. Then you can use callbacks to put the pieces together:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :form_field_label do
    # set form field label attributes (if any)
  end

  factory :form_field do
    # set form field attributes (if any)
    after(:create) do |form_field|
      FactoryGirl.create(:form_field_label, :form_field => form_field)
    end
  end

  factory :form do
    # set base attributes: form_name, etc.

    factory :form_with_fields do
      after(:create) do |form|
        FactoryGirl.create(:form_field, :form => form)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is untested, but I think it should work. Let me know if you have any problems. Also note, if you have any presence validators on these associations, you'll need to use a slightly different approach with `FactoryGirl.build`, let me know and I'll explain.

Ref: [FactoryGirl and has_many associations](http://icelab.com.au/articles/factorygirl-and-has-many-associations/)